# replacing shared library on AIX

Tags: aix

I have a shared library (.so) on AIX
I know what all processes are using it.
I have stopped all the concerned processes.
I need to replace the above .so file (with the new library) using cp -p command.
But the above command is giving error:
"Cannot remove the running program"

While i am trying "cp -p -f" it is wroking fine,
But I need to use only "cp -p"
Any idea on this matter will be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used slibclean command,then "cp -p" worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The safe way is using temporal file:

```
cp -p /from/libfoo.so /target/libfoo.so.tmp
mv -f /target/libfoo.so.tmp /target/libfoo.so
```

You don't have to stop any program to perform this; and there won't be any moment when there is no libfoo.so in target directory.

Also it doesn't hurt to call slibclean sometimes, to keep the memory clean. Use 'genkld | wc -l' before and after it to check if it has done anything.